# Why do I always need SUDO

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a Mac Book Pro and my operation system MacOS. I am coding with ionic and I have to use all command with SUDO. I don't want to do this.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
> cordova platform remove ios
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/conf/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:236
throw err
^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/kalemmacbookpro/Library/Preferences/insight-nodejs/insight-cordova.json.1908726309'
at Object.openSync (fs.js:458:3)
at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/conf/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:212:13)
at Conf.set store [as store] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/conf/index.js:142:19)
at new Conf (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/conf/index.js:44:14)
at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:40:35)
at new RelentlessInsight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:31:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:39:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32) {
errno: -13,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'EACCES',
path: '/Users/kalemmacbookpro/Library/Preferences/insight-nodejs/insight-cordova.json.1908726309'
}
    [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    
    cordova platform remove ios exited with exit code 1.
    
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

But if I use this code with SUDO, everything is normal. How can I use all ionic code without SUDO?

Comment: Can you check the ownership on the file it says you don't have permission to access? Is the file or one of the containing directories owned by root or user that isn't you, and with restricted permissions for your user?

Comment: I have set file ownership and permissions

Comment: What file(s) did you set, and what did you set them to? I'm not familiar with ionic, but this sounds like a problem where some of the files have inappropriate permissions (probably owned by root, rather than your user), so you have to run it as root (with `sudo`) to get access to them, so any new files it creates are owned by root, and the whole problem gets worse and worse over time as more and more files are owned by root rather than you. This means you may need to set ownership of *all* of the relevant files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EACCES permission errors can occur when packages are installed
> globally. If this is the case, npm may need to be set up to operate
> without elevated permissions. - [Resolving Permission Errors](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/tips#resolving-permission-errors)

**The best way to avoid permission issues is to reinstall NodeJS and npm using a node version manager.**

See the [nvm docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update) for full documentation.

**1.)** Install nvm.

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

**2.)** New terminals will now use nvm. To verify, open a new terminal and run the following. If something prints, the installation was successful.

```
$ command -v nvm
```

**3.)** To download and install the latest LTS release of NodeJS, run:

```
$ nvm install --lts
```

**4.)** Set the newly installed NodeJS as the default environment:

```
$ nvm alias default lts/*
```

**5.)** New terminals will now use the nvm-controlled NodeJS. To verify:

```
$ node -v  # will print the version installed above
$ which npm  # will print a path somewhere within the ~/.nvm folder
```

Comment: sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm ~/.npmrc

Comment: please check my another problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376428/remote-code-execution-error-when-ionic-start-project