# Remote Code Execution ERROR when ionic start project

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic4, ionic-native

```
 === npm audit security report ===  

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Remote Code Execution                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ serialize-javascript                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.1.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @ionic/angular-toolkit [dev]                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @ionic/angular-toolkit > copy-webpack-plugin >               │
│               │ serialize-javascript                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1548                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high) in 1493 scanned packages
1 vulnerability requires semver-major dependency updates.
1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

when I am starting new project with `ionic start` , I am getting this error.
how can I fix it ? Thanks all of you.

my ionic information is here

```
Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.12
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.12
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.12
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit
```

2.3.1 of Angular toolkit is released!

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities

> **To find the package that must be updated, check the “Path” field for
> the location of the package with the vulnerability**, then check for the
> package that depends on it. For example, if the path to the
> vulnerability is @package-name > dependent-package >
> package-with-vulnerability, you will need to update dependent-package.

It looks that you need to update https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin

Comment: i have installed copy-webpack-plugin package and serialize-javascript  package but i am still getting same error. i dont know how can i set path that package ?

Comment: @kalemteknoloji There is a report of that same error https://github.com/ionic-team/angular-toolkit/issues/261. Until the solution gets there I will try to reproduce it